# How can I create a custom select element using divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, select

In order to create this custom design I didn't use a select element. I tried to fetch the value in handleSubmit() but it is showing undefined in console.

[image]

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var timing = document.getElementById("timings-id");
  console.log(timing.value);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="timings" id="timings-id">
    <div value="01:00">01:00</div>
    <div value="02:00">02:00</div>
    <div value="03:00">03:00</div>
    <div value="04:00">04:00</div>
    <div value="05:00">05:00</div>
    <div value="06:00">06:00</div>
    <div value="07:00">07:00</div>
    <div value="08:00">08:00</div>
    <div value="09:00">09:00</div>
    <div value="10:00">10:00</div>
    <div value="11:00">11:00</div>
    <div value="12:00">12:00</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="handleSubmit()">BOOK<button>
</form>
```

Comment: well you can't do this because `value` is only available for some input tags

Comment: on click add item to array

Comment: can you show an example for the same scenario ?

Comment: `timings-id` is a div, and divs have no `value` attribute

Comment: Your closing button tag is missing a slash.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a module that will compute the selected hours.
You can find a simple implementation below

```js
function MultiSelect(node) {
  var statesByValue = {};
  
  
  function getSelectedValues() {
    return Object.keys(statesByValue).filter(function (value) {
      return statesByValue[value];
    });
  }
  
  
  function toggleSelection(ev) {
    var key = ev.target.dataset.value;
    var isSelected = ev.target.classList.contains('selected');
  
    statesByValue[key] = !isSelected;
    ev.target.classList.toggle('selected');
  }
  
  node.addEventListener('click', toggleSelection);
  
 
  
  return {
    getSelectedValues: getSelectedValues
  }
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');
const customSelect = MultiSelect(document.querySelector('#timings-id'));


form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(customSelect.getSelectedValues());
})
```

```css
.timings div {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="timings" id="timings-id">
     <div data-value="01:00">01:00</div>
     <div data-value="02:00">02:00</div>
     <div data-value="03:00">03:00</div>
     <div data-value="04:00">04:00</div>
     <div data-value="05:00">05:00</div>
     <div data-value="06:00">06:00</div>
     <div data-value="07:00">07:00</div>
     <div data-value="08:00">08:00</div>
     <div data-value="09:00">09:00</div>
     <div data-value="10:00">10:00</div>
     <div data-value="11:00">11:00</div>
     <div data-value="12:00">12:00</div>
   </div>
  <button type="submit">BOOK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is by assigning click event handlers to your inner div elements and then `onclick` adding a `data-value` property to the parent div.

```
const timingsDiv = document.getElementById("timings-id");
const valueDivs = timingsDiv.querySelectorAll("div");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

valueDivs.forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    timingsDiv.dataset.value = e.target.dataset.value;
  });
});

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var timing = document.getElementById("timings-id");
  console.log(timing.dataset.value);
}

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", handleSubmit);
```